# Translation of "awards", "honors", "achievements"

Tags: traduction, anglais, curriculum-vitae

I'm writing my CV in French. How should I translate the following words and phrases into French?

- Awards: prize for something
- Honors: Outstanding Graduate of University ABC (Top 5%), recipient of Dean’s List, Graduated with highest distinction
- Achievements

Comment: Trois sites pour les traductions qui fournissent des contextes : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17510/translation-of-awards-honors-achievements http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=Honors http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/Achievements

Comment: Could you link an example of CV? It's to see what are exactly Awards, Honors and Achievements to you. Because word for word translation has no sense.

Answer (score 3):

- Awards : Récompenses
- Honors : Mentions
- Achievements : Normally, i use 'Réalisations'. 'Succès' is an less used alternative. It means things you've managed to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of a CV, here is how I would translate this words (as a french native) in order of preference:

- Awards: Prix, récompenses
- Honors: Mentions would be the correct translation, but it would feel a little weird to write "Mentions: diplomée de l'université ABC..." Because the word Mentions is use with the french Baccalauéat, like "Baccalauréat S mention bien". I would prefer to write this kind of things in the education part.
- Achievements: Réalisations, which is more neutral than Succès, but the two are ok. Maybe you could give us more informations about the content.

Answer (score 2):

Awards: un prix,
Honors: mention très bien,
For the word "achievements" do you want to say like experiences and internships or skills ?